# how to separate the list into nested list ,with the average of all elements in the list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-lists

i need to separate the list into nested list with its average value.

```
 a =[ 0.6140781, 0.61407846, 0.6930427, 0.6930429, 0.7213439, 0.72134393, 0.7333274, 0.73332757]
```

the average of the list is 0.05515

if the difference between two elements is not more than 0.5515 ,i need to join the elements in the list and  if the next element in list exceeds 0.05515 then form the another list in python

desired output:

```
output : [[0.6140781, 0.61407846],[0.6930427, 0.69460429],[0.7213439, 0.72334393], [0.7333274, 0.73532757]]
```

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: wrong average for your list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the list is sorted, you can iterate through, if the current element is greater than target value, add a new list to the output, and add the current element to the most recently added list.

Your output doesn't make sense with the average number you provided because `0.7213439 - 0.69460429` is not greater than 0.05515, neither is `0.7333274 - 0.72334393` so I used 0.01 instead.

```
a = [0.6140781, 0.61407846, 0.6930427, 0.6930429, 0.7213439, 0.72134393, 0.7333274, 0.73332757]

output = [a[:1]]

for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] - a[i-1] > 0.01:
        output.append([])
    output[-1].append(a[i])

print(output)
```